# Unable to overwrite/replace existing cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to create a login system where

1) user enters email and pw 2) email and pw are verified against DB 3) token is put in the 'logins' table AND stored locally through a cookie 4) on all pages that require a login, the cookied token is checked against the token in the DB.

With that in mind, I am trying to overwrite `$_COOKIE['stored_login_token']` with the code below, but it doesn't seem to work. Basically, I have a table called 'logins' that is storing a userID, token, login date, and token expiration date. The code below is properly updating the randomly-generated token in the DB, but is not overwriting the cookie before redirecting to network_updates.php.

```
//Login Script
$mysqli2 = new mysqli($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);
$login_post_signup_token = generateRandomString();
$expiration_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+365 days'));
$suloginid = '';
$stmnt2 = $mysqli2->prepare("INSERT INTO logins (id, user, loginDate, token, expiration) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmnt2->bind_param('issss',
                    $suloginid,
                    $uuid,
                    $date,
                    $login_post_signup_token,
                    $expiration_date);

$stmnt2->execute();

$stmnt2->close();

$mysqli2->close();

setcookie(
    "stored_login_token",
    $login_post_signup_token,
    time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
    '/'
);

header('Location: network_updates.php');

exit();
```

I do have several "if" statements such as this above the setcookie() code:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($grabuserinfo) < 1) {
    header('Location: index.php?login=invalidemail');
    mysqli_close($mysqlicon);
    exit();
}
```

but I don't think that should be the root of the problem.

additionally, I created a page called "updatecookie.php" to test just updating the cookie in general, and the only code on the page is this:

```
setcookie('stored_login_token','temp123',time()+3600,'/');
header('Location: http://iseyoo.com/dev/index.php');
```

And that isn't overwriting the cookie either. Could this be something server-side?

Comment: How can you say that the cookie has not been overwritten?

Comment: I have a script on "network_updates.php" that checks the cookied token against the one in the DB and if they don't match it will redirect to "index.php". On "index.php" i have 'echo $_COOKIE['stored_login_token']' and the value that is displayed does not match what's in the DB

Comment: Wait, are you trying to have a "confirm via email" feature to your user registration? If yes, why cookie? If no, then what are you trying to do? Your code seems correct though.

Comment: Nope...I'm just trying to get a simple login system setup where

1) user enters email and pw
2) email and pw are verified against DB
3) token is put in the 'logins' table AND stored locally through a cookie
4) on all pages that require a login, the cookied token is checked against the token in the DB.

any suggestions on a better way to do this?

Comment: It looks like your login system don't work and still getting *new* random number everytime you refresh the page.

Comment: It's definitely not working, but it's because the COOKIE is not changing. That script is just part of a Form's action and is not on any page per se. Everything is working on the DB side, but I can't successfully log in because the cookied token doesn't change, unless I completely clear out the cache and start over.

Comment: Now I see, the cookie value you are using is the *old* value. On the other hand, you can use query string instead of cookie.

Comment: Correct...the cookie value is the old one from a previous login and won't update when attempting a new login. Any advice on how to handle this if I stick with cookies?